# Angular2 Child Component Validation

Tags: validation, angular

I have a form that includes a child component for a simple dropdown list. I need to require all fields on the form including the dropdown list from the child component. I am unclear on the best approach to make this happen. Currently, I have the following code which does not properly enforce the requirement for the user to select a value from the child component dropdown list.

Parent Component:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="createDisbursementAccount()" #createDisbursementAccountForm="ngForm" class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">{{ "LABELS.DISBURSEMENT_ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION" | translate }}</label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
   <input class="form-control" required maxlength="500" type="text" name="description" [(ngModel)]="disbursementAccount.description" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">{{ "LABELS.DISBURSEMENT_ACCOUNT_BANK_ACCOUNT_NAME" | translate }}</label>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
   <bank-accounts-dropdown required [(bankAccountId)]="disbursementAccount.bankAccountId" (bankAccountChanged)="bankAccountChanged($event)"></bank-accounts-dropdown>
  </div>
 </div>  
 <span class="pull-right">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" [disabled]="!createDisbursementAccountForm.form.valid">{{ "GLOBAL.SAVE_TEXT" | translate }}</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" (click)="exitDisbursementAccount()">{{ "GLOBAL.CANCEL_TEXT" | translate }}</button>
 </span>
</form>
```

Child Component:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedBankAccountId" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" [(disabled)]="isDisabled">
 <option value="" disabled>{{ "GLOBAL.DEFAULT_SELECTION" | translate }}</option>
 <option *ngFor="let bankAccount of bankAccounts" value={{bankAccount.id}}>
  {{bankAccount.name}}
 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ngDefaultControl` and `ngModel`, this way this is registered as a form control, and now you also do not need the two-way binding for bankAccountId, you can just use a simple `@Input`, the value change will be caught by the parent since `ngDefaultControl` adds two-way binding.

```html
<bank-accounts-dropdown required name="bankAccountId"
    [bankAccountId]="disbursementAccount.bankAccountId" ngModel ngDefaultControl>
</bank-accounts-dropdown>
```

### [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/7h0PxGPSnsPpyqypR7o7)

Comment: Did this help you? :)